# Chaining more than two tasks using deferred and can this be use for loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, deferred

I am getting used to `$.Deferred` just now, and it happens that I needed to chain three tasks using `$.Deferred - then`.
I created a function:

```
function processA(param1, param2) {
    log = $.post('http://domain.com/process',
                {
                   id: param1,
                   another: param2
                }
           ),
           set = log.then(function(html){
                if (someCondition) {
                    console.log('Successful');
                    // i want to do another ajax call here
                    // and chain another, that does an ajax again
                }
           })
}
```

How do I do that, as stated in the comments of my code.
Is it right? Not tested, just thought while typing this.

```
set = log.then(function(html){
      if (someCondition) {
          console.log('Successful');
          $.post(....),
          def = set.then(function(data){
             // i want to do another thing here.
          })
       }
})
```

And another thing, is it possible to use the function in a loop?
e.g.

```
data = [{param1:"...", param2:"..."}, {..., ...}]
$.each(data, function(k,v){
    processA(v.param1, v.param2);
})
```

Comment: I think something's getting lost in the explanation. There is no "third" here, only a "second". The first ajax request that is being sent is one per object in the data array, which could be any number of objects since it's an array. Next, you want to make an additional request when each one of those requests finish? or would you rather wait till all of the initial requests are done, then for each initial request send another?

Comment: uhmm, after the first request, do the second request and after the second, do the third request..

Comment: What are you calling the 3rd request? the second call to processA?

Comment: let say, first request is login, second request is setSchedule(hanging still, submitted but not yet save on the database), third request is finalize the submitted Schedule, by posting again.. does this make sense?

Comment: Yes. One more question, Do you need to ensure that the first three are complete before the next three get sent? If that's the case, the below answer i gave won't exactly work because it's going to try to do them all at once, but in sequence for each entry in `data`

Comment: Yes. The first needs to be completed before the second, and the second needs to be completed before the third. And if looped, it must not processA at the same time, causing if example multiple logins, that doesn't make sense..

Comment: Ok, i'll modify to fit that requirement then.

Comment: you deleted your answer?

Comment: I did, as it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I wrote for a dice game. Rolling the dice, each `dice.roll()` gets stored into a `$.Deferred` object. When all dice have run their animation, you can execute your callbacks or whatever.

```
var promises = [];

// collect promises
_.each(fDice, function (die) {
    promises.push(function () {
        return $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
            $(die).roll(options, function (data) {
                dfd.resolve(data); // resolve the state
            });
        }).promise(); // send it back
    });
});

// roll selected dice
dfrAll(promises).done(function () {
    // do something here
});

dfrAll: function (array) {
    /// <summary>Resolves n $.Deferred functions from an Array</summary>
    /// <param name="Array" type="Array">An Array of $.Deferred functions</param>
    /// <returns type="Deferred" />
    var dfd = $.Deferred(),
        len = array.length,
        results = [];

    if (len === 0) {
        dfd.resolve(results);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var promise = array[i];
            $.when(promise()).then(function (value) {
                results.push(value);
                if (results.length === len) {
                    dfd.resolve(results);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

For me the storage of deferred functions into an array was the key to resolve my animations. Hope it helps.

Comment: You could get rid of `$.when` the way you're using it, `yambo.fn.dfrAll(promises).then(...`

Comment: Hmm, can try that, but there's another functionality on my button that applies the "keeprolling" option. When I release, it will execute the other one. I'm still trying to optimize though.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#tutorial/chaining) better explained chaining promises:

```
function authenticate() {
    return getUsername()
    .then(function (username) {
        return getUser(username);
    })
    // chained because we will not need the user name in the next event
    .then(function (user) {
        return getPassword()
        // nested because we need both user and password next
        .then(function (password) {
            if (user.passwordHash !== hash(password)) {
                throw new Error("Can't authenticate");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: are you sure this pattern works for jquery's implementation? I think you may need to wrap all the returns and throws in new deferred instances...